# Cyclomatic Complexity Calculation on Presenter Methods and Callbacks

Tags: android, cyclomatic-complexity, white-box-testing, white-box

everyone.
I need help in determining the cyclomatic complexity regarding this tested method.

```
    @Override
public void renderData() {
    mRepository.render(new TvShowsRepositoryCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onRenderingData() {
            Objects.requireNonNull(getView()).setCurrentlyRenderingView();
        }

        @Override
        public void onRenderDataSuccessful(List<TvShow> shows) {
            Objects.requireNonNull(getView()).setSuccessfulRenderingView(shows);
        }

        @Override
        public void onRenderDataSuccessfulWithZeroItems() {
            Objects.requireNonNull(getView()).setUnsuccessfulRenderingView();
        }

        @Override
        public void onRenderDataError() {
            Objects.requireNonNull(getView()).setUnsuccessfulRenderingView();
        }
    });
}
```

If it is a mere/simple Java class it is easy to test and determine the basis path. However, in the tested method above I can not think how to calculate its cyclomatic complexity. As well as determining the predicate nodes.

Thanks all for your help.